# "Project X" vs "X Project"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, reference

Say you want to refer to your project which you have chosen the name "X" for it. What is the difference in referring to it as "Project X" or "X Project"? Is the first one more suitable for branding? I am not a native English speaker so I am not sure if they feel and/or have grammatically different usage.

Comment: My take: Project X sounds more like X is the name of the project; X Project sounds like a project having to do with X. Let X = Zebra. Project Zebra = Zebra is name of project. Zebra Project ~= unnamed project about Zebras.

Comment: We’re looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions, showing research effort and posed as you would ask them of an expert. Questions which do not share research effort may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I've been trying to find similar articles on the web or here but I couldn't find something similar to this. So, I was not able to refer to any discussions on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of typical usage, "Project X" uses the word *Project* as a title and doesn't require a determiner. The project's name includes the leading word *Project*, as "[Project America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_America)" illustrates.

The word *project* can also be used as a simple noun in the form "the project X" where X is the name of the project. It is less common, and either relegates X to near parenthetical status or promotes it theatrically. This form, however, is more commonly used where X is an attribute of the project, for example in the following title.

- Common Challenges in the Project Life Cycle
  [- Brandeis University](http://projectmgmt.brandeis.edu/resources/articles/common-challenges-in-the-project-life-cycle/)

The second form, "the X project", is always used with a determiner such as the definite article. Here, the word [*project*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/project) is treated as a simple noun that takes *X* as an adjective as illustrated by the following sentence:

- Your president or business owner may not be directly involved in the website project, but in most cases they still have a strong sense of what they want and don’t want on a website.
  [- tbhcreative](http://blog.tbhcreative.com/2015/11/how-to-organize-your-website-project.html)

The second form can be treated as a proper noun (e.g. [The Hunger Project](http://www.thp.org/)), in which case both the determiner and the trailing *Project* are included.

Answer (score 0):

"Project X" is like a proper noun in a way because it is the official naming of the project meaning the project itself is named Project X. "X Project" sounds more vague and general as in when people say "X variable/Y variable" or it is like another way of saying "etc" such as "Tom had a lot of excuses. He said his car wouldn't start, he woke up late and xyz." So if you have a project and you want to call it X you should refer to it as Project X

Comment: Counterexamples are not hard to find; most people have heard of the Manhattan Project and the Human Genome Project for example.

Comment: @choster, Those work because of the "the" in front of them.